# What is a popular entropy source for seeding a CSPRNG, which is actually weak and unreliable?

Tags: randomness, entropy

Say I want to seed a CSPRNG. What sources are popular, but unreliable? What sources should I even use?

Comment: it will be good to combine this with your previous question.

Comment: Any language-specific `rand()` is commonly (mis)used as a cryptographic seed.

Comment: Using the current time and date is popular, but unreliable. Oh, abd also totally insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is for your personal use, randomness collected from mouse movements can be an option. Veracrypt uses this. If it is to be done on a large scale, try using **Lava Lamps.**
If these seem unviable, try using the *Urandom* pool.

Comment: Do you have _"What sources are popular, but unreliable?"_ the right way around?  Lava lamps are a pretty perfect source of entropy (Rayleigh–Bénard convection/deterministic chaotic systems).   I also suggest changing to `/dev/random` if you're looking for perfect but unreliable entropy sources.

Comment: It's important to realise that Thomas Hühn's silly 'myth' post is just a flawed and dangerous  internet   mime that seems to catch out young players.  See and digest Mr. Pornin's acute comment in said post regarding the fundamental difference that is appropriate to this (and all other) question(s).

Comment: @PaulUszak That "myth" post is not flawed. As someone who has read both the current LinuxRNG documentation and is familiar with the driver source code itself, I can say the only issues his post has is a few oversimplifications and a tiny mistake caused by him missing a change to the driver that came in kernel 4.8. But the idea behind is post is _absolutely correct_. Your view that you need the blocking pool to be secure is simply wrong. It's only perfect _in theory_ if the entropy estimation is perfect, which it is not.